# Files > Other Locations free disk space and Disks free disk space differs

Tags: 22.04, files

The problem is when I check the space left on the device at Files application  shows 0 bytes although the Disks application shows 24GB.

Files application:

[image: Files application]

Disks application

[image: Disks application]

Also when I try to transfer something via Filezilla FTP application I get an error message as "error while writing local file" sounds as no space left on device.

It'd be appriciated if anyone says the reason for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The applications themselves give you the answer. On Linux, the filesystem reserves 5% for root use ([see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)).

Therefore, the "files" app reports 0% free (because it knows the last 5% is reserved, and not usable right away).

On the other hand the "disks" app does not know about the filesystem reserved space. So this rightly reports 5% free (which is reserved by the filesystem).

You can lower the reserved blocks percentage with this command:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sde1
```

This will reduce reserved blocks to 1% instead of 5% (which is more than enough for drives over 100 GB).